# Новое слово диписточник

Tags: словообразование, неологизмы

Что-то не так с этим словом. Не так — на письме, это ясно. Звучит нормально, а записано без учёта твёрдого П. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Не что-то не так, а не так — на письме, это ясно?

Comment: Да, я ответил.>

Answer (score 1):

> Что-то не так с этим словом. Не так — на письме, это ясно. Звучит
>   нормально, а записано без учёта твёрдого П. Как можно исправить?

Никак. И не надо. А это в русском языке единственный прием для передачи твердости согласного на стыке морфов типа "согласная-гласная переднего ряда" - это замена корневого И на Ы. Но составные слова подобного типа не требуют и не допускают подобной орфографической замены.

Вообще этот прием применяется только на стыке корня и приставки - да и то не всякой, а только чисто русской и первичной (или как там они называются, забыл), если префикс - приставка "импортная" или образованная от смыслового морфа (типа "сверх" или "контр"), то замена на требуется (сверхиндустриальный, контринформативный и т.п.). То же можно сказать и в отношении слов с двумя корневыми морфами.

Вообще лопатинская Орфографическая Комиссия в свое время предлагала несколько расширить сферу применения этой замены, но и то очень ограниченно, только на некоторые "обрусевшие" приставки. Замена в составных словах даже не обсуждалась.

Comment: В русском языке — приём единственный. Но первая-то часть слова французская.

Answer (score 0):

Если этот *диписточник* — пробный шар, то он обречён: не появятся слова, обобщающие государственные и не структурные, такие как дум-, фед-, прав-, фин-, счёт-, миг-, след-, обр-, здрав- да и другие источники. Гораздо проще называть организацию, чем втискивать пусть и краткое её имя или профиль в заведомо сложное слово, изобретая велосипед.

Относительно того, — можно ли, если очень хочется расширения словарного запаса из принципа. Можно предложить применить здесь решение по гибридному типу (***pr-директо***р, ***пин-код***), а также традиционную подмену И на твёрдую Ы, испытанную на **предыстории**, **розыгрыше**, ***возыметь***. Есть и такой путь: увеличение первой части до четырёх букв — диплисточник.